# xlsxwriter code (in python) not freezing top row

Tags: xlsxwriter

I am using the below code xlsxwriter code to freeze the top row of my excel sheet.  However the code is **not** freezing the top row at all. Any ideas?

```
    import xlsxwriter 
    ...
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(XLSX_FILE)
    currentWorksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(k)
    currentWorksheet.write("A1", "User ID")
    currentWorksheet.write("B1", "Name")
    currentWorksheet.write("C1", "Email")
    currentWorksheet.write("D1", "Mobile App access")
    currentWorksheet.write("E1", "Dashboard access")
    currentWorksheet.write("F1", "Registrations complete")

    currentWorksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0) # Freeze the Header Row
```

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean? Is it not taking any action, or raising an exception, or printing any error messages?

Comment: Sorry. My apologies.  I meant to say that the code is not freezing the top row at all. Original post has been updated.

Comment: The code calls `get_worksheet_by_name()` immediately after it creates the new xlsx file which won't work unless you have already created a worksheet in the new xlsx workbook. Are you trying to update an existing file? Because that isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to update an existing file.  As you can see in my original posting, I have creating the header labels (User ID, Name, etc.), and I simply want to freeze this header row in place.  Why is the not supported by XlsxWriter?

Comment: XlsxWriter [doesn't support updating](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/introduction.html) an existing file.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know that.  OK.  Thanks all.  I will find another course of action then.